# Custom Canonical plugin throws "404 - page not found" error when enabled for Tags

Tags: plugin, tags

I use Joomla Custom Canonical plugin for creating the canonical links. It works well, except for the tags: If I switch on the canonical creation for tags and then some of the tags, will drop a 404 error.

But not for all tags.

For the usual tags ".../component/tags/tag/..." the Custom Canonical works well.
But if I create a "Compact list of tagged items" Menu Item, then it drops a 404 - page not found error.

The site I am trying to fix the canonical: https://www.szerver.hu/

An example Compact list of tagged items Menu Item: https://www.szerver.hu/munkaallomasok/

Have you met this issue before?

Comment: In which Joomla version?

Comment: Hi Zollie, the versions are: Joomla! - 3.10.0 & Custom Canonical - Site Plugin - 1.2.1

Comment: The easiest solution would be if you just drop an email to the developer of this custom plugin, since the plugin was last updated almost a year ago, so it could have few issues on Joomla 3.10 and the developer has an immediate overview of his plugin. https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/custom-canonical/